# How to display only selected products in Spree?

Tags: e-commerce, spree

Am using Spree Commerce, and right now every product I add on my backend is displayed on the homepage. Is there a way that I can display only products of my choice on the frontpage, and not display everything as it does by default?

I know deface allows me to customise the look of everything, but it is not the answer I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@elliot Actually it's pretty simple. Go to product's edit page on admin end and set `discontinue_on` for that product with a date equal to the current date or lesser.
Only those product are visible on the frontend for which `available_on` is lesser than the current date and `discontinue_on` is greater than the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Deface is used to changing views not a controllers. A fetching products from DB is a controller logic.

There is a lot of options, you can add your own scopes in product model and override controller to use them, but fastest is use `discontinue_on` because for not admin user spree uses usually `active` scope on products.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I just changed                                                           @products = @searcher.retrieve_products to                                       @products = Product.joins(:variants_including_master).where(:name => "Ruby on Rails Tote").uniq on my index action in home_controller_decorator.rb

Comment: This solution is not a best idea. You are hardcoding the controller to show only products with a given name, ("Ruby on Rails Tote"). If you want to have more clean solution use some custom scope in model on default search in controller. Spree in default is using ransack to creating querries.